# Command line arguments to get total errors during compilation in gcc compiler

Tags: gcc, command-line-arguments

Is there any command line argument to list the total number of errors in the particular compilation. This would be useful when solving a hell lot of errors or when the sources are large in number.

> IDE's like Eclipse used to list the total number of errors and warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any command line argument to list the total number of errors in the particular compilation

No there isn't. The feature was requested by [GCC bug 26061](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26061), Feb. 2006,
which has never been accepted.

Comment: @iamnagaky You're welcome, and welcome to SO. Please see[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)